# Symfony 4 & webpack encore in production env, my css and js generated files aren't loaded

Tags: symfony, assets, symfony4, production, webpack-encore

I want to deploy my Symfony 4 website in a production environment.
I set the variable `APP_ENV`to `prod` (in the .env file), and I executed this command : `yarn build` ( = `./node_modules/.bin/encore production` )

Then, I can see there are generated files in my public directory (files like by example : `public/build/css/global.9e04a9d9.css`, `public/build/js/global.399763b8.js`, ... )

I can see also a manifest.json file in the `public/build` directory, its content is :

```
{
  "myApp/public/build/js/global.js": "/myApp/public/build/js/global.399763b8.js",
  "myApp/public/build/css/global.css": "/myApp/public/build/css/global.9e04a9d9.css"
}
```

But when I load a page thought my browser (firefox), css and js files aren't loaded and I don't understand why.

By example, in the browser debugger I get this 'notice' message : "Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost/myApp/public/build/js/global.js”."

And when I browse the code of my page (via firefox debugger), the paths of css and js are :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/myApp/public/build/css/global.css">
...
<script src="/myApp/public/build/js/global.js"></script>
```

The issue is here : Why `global.css` and `global.js` aren't `global.9e04a9d9.css` and `global.399763b8.js` ?

- I cleared caches with `bin/console cache:clear` (and I tried also with `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`)
- I checked rights of var/cache and public/build directories (directories owned by www-data with read/write permission)

Of course, in my template twig file, I generate theses paths with the function "asset" :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/css/global.css') }}">
...
<script src="{{ asset('build/js/global.js') }}"></script>
```

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to tell in order. Initally, you need to install this package.

`composer require asset`

Further, you'll see asset.yaml in `config/packages/asset.yaml``

Insert these lines,

`framework:
    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'`

By the way, make sure that you use `asset` function in Twig to include your assets files, like this;

`<script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}">`